# why push notifications are not working in prodection mode?

Tags: ios4, ios-4.2, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am working with my first iphone app. and now i am working with push notifications. i am using urban airship for push notifications. in developement phase everything was working fine. device tokens were registered and then i could send push notifications from urban airship. but its not working with production phase. i put my app on app store but push notifications didnt work. i tried to search alot on urban airship to solve this problem but couldn't. I think there is something i have to change when i make binary file for that app. can anyone help me with this? any tutorial which will help me. Its working fine in development phase but not working in production phase. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue at my company a couple months back.

There are two sets of urbanairship credentials (by credentials I mean: Application Key, Application Secret, Application Master Secret) sandbox and production. When you were developing the product, you were using the development credentials and everything worked great. Those will not work after you release the application to the AppStore due to the way urbanairship works with Apple's Notification sandbox etc etc.

Track down the production credentials on urbanairship and change them out in your source code before resubmitting and you should be all set. You'll need to do an adhoc build to verify (I believe). Good luck!

Documentation on Development/Production settings: http://urbanairship.com/docs/push_index.html#development-or-production

Comment: can you send me some link or document which tells how to do that and how to do an adhoc build? Thanks

Comment: AdHoc build for XCode 4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295890/iphone-ad-hoc-build-using-xcode-4

Comment: one more question. i tried to get help from urban and they wrote this to me "When you moved to production, did you remember to change the application key for Urban Airship in the Airshipconfig.plist file?" whats that Airshipconfig.plist. i asked them too but didn't get any answer yet. Development push SSL certificate and production push SSL certificate are different? Do i have to buy a new certificate for production? thanx in advance

Comment: Its probably just a plist file containing your UrbanAirship credentials. They might be assuming you are loading the credentials from a plist file called "Airshipconfig.plist". You shouldn't have to buy a certificate for production.