# iphone app don't want to build my ipa

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I want to test my app on a device, so I encode my device on the portal, 
I made a new a distribution provisioning profile on ad-hoc mode. I download it, 
and install it on my XCODE.

I checked on the informations about project and targets (all sounds correct but I'm not a specialist of those configuration) :

[first shot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/capturedcran20120116145.png/) [second shot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/capturedcran20120116145.png/)

And When I build for provisionning (with appname>IOS Device next to the "Play" button), it gives me :

```
error: error reading property list '/Users/...iphone application V1.0/e-mars/emars.entitlements' - property list has no object
Command builtin-productPackagingUtility failed with exit code 1
```

Could you please help me?

**EDIT : **
Product : Build for : Build for Profiling (and normal build with the emulator) run when I select emars > iPhone Simulator next to the play button

**EDIT 2 : **
I've tried to change the Bundle identifier :
I had com.elsingor.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} and I put com.elsingor but it's the same issue...

**EDIT 3**
I'va created a new Entitlements and edit the reference in the plist to the new entitlements and...
Now I build with myApName>IOS Device on clicking on Build for archiving.

I again have a problem; I didn't see the Archive in the Organizer! Please help me :-/

**FINAL EDIT :**

I tried to press simply Build instread of build > build archive and it works for me !

Comment: have you updated the appId information in App_info.plist file ?

Comment: Ali3n : Thanks? What are those informations? I use the same project that I used to publish the initial app (with the same distribution certificate) , and I don't understand why I wil change something. Please explain to me :-)

Comment: @Aram : yes, it works in the simulator!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements?

Comment: I have update the initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i followed this tutorial to do my ad hoc builds
http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1237

but you can of course also take a look at the documentation at testflightapps.com
http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

you will see in the first post they talk about creating an entitlements.plist file and maybe thats where your problems is.  i would also say because i ran into this problem, when everything is done and its time to "Archive" make sure the simulator is not selected.  iOS Device needs to be selected for Archive to not be greyed out.
[iPhone ad hoc build using Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295890/iphone-ad-hoc-build-using-xcode-4)

i have never done an adhoc build on its own, i always use testflightapps.com to distribute (so for this you will need a distribution cert as well) my apps and i recommend using them.  Overall it was a fairly simple process and they do have free accounts so theres no reason not to use their service.

Comment: Apparently, since Xcode4, you don't have to make entitlements.plist ... and I'm 4.1. I followed your first link and I get again the same error

Comment: the file still needs to be there, is what i have found and even what they say in that first link.  myn is empty.

Comment: OK THANKS, you're Right, Now The Archive build BUT I didn't see the Archive in the Organizer... damned soul...

Comment: stupid question i know but when the organizer comes up you did click on the tab labelled "Archives" right?

Comment: I've created a new entitlements and I press Archive instread of Build > Build Archive Thanks to all !

Comment: i think then my answer would be more of the right one?  if it was the entitlements page i think u should switch the answer, dont care that much but future people who find this post will look towards the wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test on your device, do a development build instead of adhoc.

Go to the iOS Provisioning Portal in the dev center (https://developer.apple.com)

1) First you need to add your device.

2) Create a **Development Profile** - include this device in it.

3) Download and install in xcode.

4) Select this profile in the **Code Signing** section of Project and Target Build Settings

5) Connect your device to the computer you are working on

6) Select **scheme** that corresponds to your device (if you have an iphone it will Read 
iPhone your.ios.version)

7) Hit Run - the code will build, install the app on your device, run it and will connect the debugger.