# Creating a provisioning profile for a device id

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

I have been given an iPhone device ID and asked to create a provisioning profile (or something where he could run it on his device) for that device ID so he could run it on his device.

How can I do this? This might sound duplicate for some, but I am really lost. Can someone provide me steps to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You should have access to some Apple Developer Program (iOS Developer Program in your case). And after successful login to this Program on the developer.apple.com you can see something like this:

[image]

Enter into iOS Provisioning Portal and select Provisioning section. You can find there How To area which fully describes this procedure.

[image]

Comment: I have done this for my device, and it works successfully. But i don't know how to add somebody else's device to it. Do i have to follow each and every step again (or is there any steps i need to avoid) ? Help

Comment: Just open Devices section and add new one. Probably you will need to re-download new provision profile.

Comment: What do i send this person, is it only the provisioning profile ? Can he run the app if i only  provide him the provisioning profile ?

Comment: Yes, you need to compile and build you app with this newly created profile and then send profile and .app to your client.

Comment: Have you come across any tutorial/videotutorial that gives step by step instructions ?

Comment: I used How To section on the apple.developer.com. It was very clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

research testflightapp.com (for distributing after cert creation) but really you will need to create the cert on the apple dev site.  so go to the dev site, login, go to ios provisioning and walk through the steps to create your certs.

Comment: I have gone through `testflightapp.com`, but i found it a bit confusing since i didn't know how to add the project and create the profiles. I'll Google this a bit more. could you kindly tell me a good search term ?

Comment: after creating the main developer cert , add devices to your profile, you should also create an adhoc distribution profile as well, when creating this you will end up selecting that device.  see my answer to this post for more info on building the adhoc distribution certificate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881063/iphone-app-dont-want-to-build-my-ipa/8882023#8882023