# How to generate an iPA file using only development certificate in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, certificate, ipa

I dont have a paid account at apple site. Therefore my client sent me development certificate after creating provisioning profile there. Now he asked me to load this certificate in xcode and generate an executable or ipa file to test the application in iPhone device.

Can anybody tell me the way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295890/iphone-ad-hoc-build-using-xcode-4

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I do that following these steps:

1. Build the source code
2. Go to Organizer > Projects and select your project, then open the derived data folder by clicking on the arrow.
3. Locate the .app file (usually Build > Products > Debug-iphoneos) and drop it to iTunes
4. Pick the app from iTunes and drop it to the desktop for example. iTunes will convert that to ipa.

Comment: Is this method ok for distribution for testing in case tester's devices are in the provisioning profile? Meaning if I obtain an .ipa via iTunes conversion and send it view email or testflightapp service will tester be able to install it on his devices without issues? Or I still have to gain a distribution certificate and create an .ipa with Xcode for this?

Comment: Since iTunes 12.7, it looks like iTunes does not support 'app options' anymore. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672260/1010443) worked for me, and it doesn't need iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Do the Following steps:
1) First get the provisioning profile.

2) Set the debug mode to iOS device.

3) Go to Product, Select Archive and ur project will be Archived.

4) Next Go to Organizer, select the created archive u have created. Then click share. It will ask u to Allow or not. Select allow. You can set name of the app . Finally ur ipa file is created

Comment: where that 'share' option is? Can't see one in Xcode6

Answer (score -4):

1) First complete your coding check it with your provisioning profile.

2) Then click to run on device iPhone or iPad.

3) then go to menu -> prodcut -> clean.

4) After cleaning menu -> product -> Archive .

5) After completing it click on distribute and then select the option for save as enterprise or adhoc application and click on next button.

6) It will take a minute as per your app file size.

7) then give a name of ipa and save it where you want.

Comment: This doesn't address the desire to use a development certificate.