# How to convert an archive (.app) to .ipa in iTunes 12.7.0 onwards?

Tags: ios, itunes

The new iTunes version 12.7.0 has missing Apps tab where all the iOS apps were seen. I'm looking for the new way.

Appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Why don't you use Xcode Archive?

Comment: I extracted .app from XCode archive.

Comment: `.ipa` is for iOS, `.app` is for macOS. Which are you talking about? Also, you can export an Xcode project to `.ipa` inside Xcode only. Are you asking how to install the `.ipa` to a device?

Comment: @user550088 Once you run Xcode Archive. Use the Export button on the archive to create the ipa.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not a member of  registered development team.

Comment: Then have the developers send you an ipa instead of an app. Where are you getting an app anyway?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Got a solution.

XCode -> Archive -> Select project in Organizer -> Show in Finder -> Show Package contents -> Products -> Applications -> "Product.app".

Create a folder named "Payload" -> Put "Product.app" with in "Payload" -> Compress "Payload" -> Get "Payload.zip" -> Change name to "Product.ipa".

For installing instructions in iTunes 12.7.0 please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224843/with-apps-option-removed-from-latest-itunes-12-7-how-to-install-adhoc-ipa).

Comment: Not sure if the question is valid, is the folder name "Payload" case sensitive? as sometimes the generated ipa does not get installed.

Comment: @sabin "Payload.zip" is just a wrapper name and eventually its needs to be changed to "Product_Name.ipa". Please try using  "Payload.zip" and check your signing certificates.

Comment: Can't the folder initially be named Product?

Comment: Could you install it after that or do you receive a msg that says "integrity of app could not be verified"