# Test my Titanium application on multiple iPhone devices not via iTunes?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, titanium, itunes

I'd like to test my application made by Titanium mobile on multiple devices.

The issue is, I do not care whatever would happen on my iphone, but not on the other iphones.
Actually, I just have only one iphone, but I need to test on more than several devices (iPhone, iPhone 4, iPad, iPod) so I now borrow some of them from my friends.
Since my friends seriously do not want me to mess their devices up, I need to do test with no trouble such as losing their applications data.

and I did some research about this, and now I understand if I import my application to their devices through the right way formally recommended by appcelerator, those devices will lose their individual data because it's implemented via my iTunes.

Is there any good way to achieve my testing ?

I would really appreciate it if anyone show the way.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should try out the [Ad Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295890/iphone-ad-hoc-build-using-xcode-4):

> With Ad Hoc distribution you can share your application with up to 100
>   other iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch users. Through email or by posting
>   it to a website or server, users can download and install your app.

or check out [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/)

> A free testing service for mobile developers, managers and testers.